# What is the Gateaux derivative of the norm $||\cdot||_p$ on $\mathcal{L}^{\mathbb{R}}_{p}([0,1])$?

Tags: functional-analysis, derivatives, lebesgue-integral, banach-spaces

To get the Gateaux derivative of the norm $||\cdot||_p$ on $\mathcal{L}^{\mathbb{R}}_{p}([0,1])$, I have to do a manual computation of the derivative and, then, use the definition of Gateaux differentiablity. Now, kindly check out what I have done so far. Define $f:U\longrightarrow\mathbb{R}:\,x\mapsto$ $||x||_p,\,p\in(1,\infty),$ where $U$ is a closed and convex subset of $\mathcal{L}^{\mathbb{R}}_{p}([0,1]).$ Let $x\in U\setminus\{0\}.$ Then, by direct computation, 
\begin{align}
Df(x)&=D\left(\int_{0}^{1}|x(t)|^pdt \right)^{\frac{1}{p}}\\&= \frac{1}{p}\left(\int_{0}^{1}|x(t)|^pdt \right)^{\frac{1}{p}-1}   D\left(\int_{0}^{1}|x(t)|^pdt \right)\\&= \frac{1}{p}\left(\int_{0}^{1}|x(t)|^pdt \right)^{\frac{1-p}{p}}  \int_{0}^{1}p\,|x(t)|^{p-1}D|x(t)|dt \\&= ||x||_p^{1-p}  \int_{0}^{1}|x(t)|^{p-1}\frac{x(t)}{|x(t)|}dt\\&= ||x||_p^{1-p}  \int_{0}^{1}|x(t)|^{p-1}\text{sign}(x(t)) dt. 
\end{align}
Applying $(Df)(x)$ to any $h\in U$ close to $x$, we get
\begin{align}
\langle Df(x),h\rangle&=||x||_p^{1-p}  \int_{0}^{1}|x(t)|^{p-1}\text{sign}(x(t))h(t)dt.
\end{align}
Let me start my question here: I was thinking I should get
\begin{align}
\langle Df(x),h\rangle&=\dfrac{1}{||x||_p } \int_{0}^{1}x(t)h(t)dt.
\end{align}
Please, what is wrong with my thinking. Any way out?

Answer (score 1):

The direct computation is correct, your expectations were wrong. To see this, calculate the derivative of 
$$
x\mapsto \sqrt[p]{|x|^p+1}.
$$
The chain rule will produce this factor $sign(x) |x|^{p-1}$. Also, no cancellation can happen between $|x|^{p-1}$ and powers of $|x|^p+1$.