Derivative of $L^p$ norm
I don't see any sources stating the derivative of the $L^p$ norm. I'm trying to use the same logic as is done for the $l^p$ norm (see this post).
Let $\Omega \subset \mathbb{R}^n$ be some domain. The $L^p$ norm for functions in $L^p(\Omega)$ is defined as
$$ \|f\|_p = \left(\int_\Omega |f(x)|^p dx \right)^{1/p}\,. $$
What is the derivative of the $L^p$ norm?
Let $h(g) = g^{1/p}$. Let $g(f(x)) = \int_\Omega |f(x)|^p dx$.
Chain rule for $h(g(f(x)))$ gives
\begin{align*}
\frac{d}{df} \left(\int_\Omega |f(x)|^p dx \right)^{1/p}
&= \frac{1}{p} \left(\int_\Omega |f(x)|^p dx \right)^{1/p-1} \frac{d}{df} \left( \int_\Omega |f(x)|^p dx \right)
\\
&= \frac{1}{p} \left(\int_\Omega |f(x)|^p dx \right)^{1/p-1}  \int_\Omega p|f(x)|^{p-1} \text{sign}(f(x)) dx 
\\
&= \left(\int_\Omega |f(x)|^p dx \right)^{1/p-1} \int_\Omega |f(x)|^{p-2} f(x) dx
\\
&= \|f\|_p^{1-p} \int_\Omega |f(x)|^{p-2} f(x) dx\,.
\end{align*}
Can this be simplified more? The reasoning from the post about $l^p$ has a kronecker delta that wouldn't work in the $L^p$ case.
Edit: the post linked in the comment arrives at the same expression. The LHS of my expression from $\frac{d}{df} \|f\|_p$ is imprecise because a derivative "with respect to $f$" is actually a directional derivative in $L^p$ space.  My question still holds: what is the best way to express the derivative of $\|f\|_p$? Does it have to be expressed via an inner product as is done in the linked post?

Another way to think about the inside might be $|f|^{p-1}\mathrm{sgn}(f)$

This is wrong. The derivative wrt $f$ is an element in the dual space, not a number. You need to compute the directional derivative. The correct expression can be found, e.g., in this post https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3624949/what-is-the-gateaux-derivative-of-the-norm-cdot-p-on-mathcall-mathb?rq=1

@daw thanks for the reference. so I guess the right answer is that we can only think about "weak derivatives"; that weak derivative is defined in the formula for $\langle Df, h\rangle$ in your linked question. is that correct?

It is not a weak derivative, it is a directional derivative.

@daw added an edit. I'm still not sure how to express the derivative -- is there a closed form, or do we have to work with inner products (which is why I thought it was a weak derivative).

@900edges It is not an inner product. If $f: E\to F$ is a map, a «derivative» of $f$ at a point $x_0$ is also a map $Df(x_0): E\to F$, so for each $h$ in $E$, $Df(x_0)(h) \in F$. Usually, as in Frechet derivative, $Df(x_0)$ is required to be a bounded linear functional. Here my intuition is that the norm is Gateaux differentiable but not Frechet differentiable in general, although the Gateaux derivative turns out to be a bounded linear functional.

@Gribouillis is there a closed form for the Gateaux derivative of $| \cdot |^p_p$?

@900edges What is a closed form for a linear map? Here, when $1<p<\infty$, the Gateaux derivative of $\Psi: f\mapsto |f|_p^p$ appears to be the linear map $h \mapsto D\Psi(f). h = \int p |f(x)|^{p-1}\text{sgn}(f(x)) h(x) dx$ from $L^p$ to $\mathbb R$. I doubt you find a simpler formulation.

@Gribouillis that makes sense. I appreciate it.

@900edges You could perhaps avoid the $h$ by remembering that the dual of $L^p$ can be identified with $L^q$ such that $1/p + 1/q = 1$, then you could say that the Gateaux-derivative of $\Psi$ is the map $D\Psi: L^p\rightarrow L^q$ defined by $D\Psi(f) = p |f|^{p-1} \text{sgn}(f)$.
